# photo carousel viewer in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am interested in building or using an open source widget to display photos on a website, using angular.js. Searching Google for "Angular.js photo carousel" or "angular.js photo viewer" returns only a couple of examples.

Are there a lot of angular.js photo widgets siloed somewhere I don't know about, or is this the sort of thing I just need to write rom scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular bootstrap has a carousel: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
(but I image you already found that)

Otherwise it would probably be pretty easy to write a directive to setup a jquery plugin that you like.

You might try searching for "image/photo slider".

Comment: Yeah, we implemented that one, but didn't like some things about it, like it only showed one photo at a time. 

We were also trying to avoid using JQuery at all actually, preferring a little pain to keep it pure angular.js for now. Is using JQuery widgets through angular a typical thing?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson I think your intuition is generally good.  Sticking to pure Angular is probably a good idea.  That said I've done some integration with Facebook social media plugins, EventBrite JS API, and more relevant to the topic RoyalSlider JS a slider component from CodeCanyon (jQuery based).  It works perfectly well and I was able to easily wrap it up in a directive so it still feels like angular despite being a jQuery component wrapped in there.  I think if the bootstrap one doesn't work exactly as you like just fork it and go from there.

Comment: Wrapping up jquery or other third party widgets in directives works well.

Answer (score 0):

I like the AngularJS Touch Carousel devices from revolunet: https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel
I use it for example here: http://www.nautischer-verein-cuxhaven.de